# Countdown Timer Not Counting Down

Tags: jquery

### [>> View On CodePen <<](https://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/eRXJxL?editors=1010)

### My Script

```
var timer = 60;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    timer--;

    var H  = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var HH = (H < 9 ? "0" : "") + H;
    var M  = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var MM = (M < 9 ? "0" : "") + M;
    var S  = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var SS = (S < 9 ? "0" : "") + S;

    $('.timer').text(HH + ":" + MM + ":" + SS);
    if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

### Questions

Well I'm not sure what to ask here, I'm pretty sure this should work following tutorials online for a live jQuery based timer. I've set the `timer`, obtain the hours, minutes and seconds, adding a `0` if the `value < 9`, yet the script isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the value of `timer`. The calculations are all done in milliseconds, but I think you're using seconds for the `timer`.

I've made a fix for that in the snippet below. I've also added three variables at the top so it's easier to define the starting value of the timer. You can simply set the initial number of hours, minutes and seconds and from there it will all be calculated to milliseconds.

In the example I've set the initial value to 03:00:08, so you don't have to wait a long time to see it jump to a new minute and hour.

```js
var timerH = 3;
var timerM = 0;
var timerS = 8;
var timer = (timerH * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (timerM * 60 * 1000) + (timerS * 1000);

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    timer -= 1000;
  
    var H  = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var HH = (H < 9 ? "0" : "") + H;
    var M  = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var MM = (M < 9 ? "0" : "") + M;
    var S  = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var SS = (S < 9 ? "0" : "") + S;
  
    $('.timer').text(HH + ":" + MM + ":" + SS);
    if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Realising this from your answer, I have updated [my version](https://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/eRXJxL?editors=1010) changing all instances of `1000` to `100` and the seconds appear to be the minutes, which is also the case when I change the input time to miliseconds format so there is more to this than I first thought!

Comment: @TimMarshall In your new version you still have `timer--;`, which should be `timer -= 1000;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)